# Split list in a column to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have two DataFrames as below:

**df1.shape = (4,2)**

| Text | Topic |
| --- | --- |
| Where is the party tonight? | Party |
| Let's dance | Party |
| Hello world | Other |
| It is rainy today | Weather |

**df2.shape(4,2)**

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Where is the party tonight? | [-0.011570500209927559, -0.010117080062627792,….,0.062448356] |
| Let's dance | [-0.08268199861049652, -0.0016140303341671824,….,0.02094201] |
| Hello world | [-0.0637684240937233, -0.01590338535606861,….,0.02094201] |
| It is rainy today | [0.06379614025354385, -0.02878064103424549,….,0.056790903] |

Basically `df2` is the embedding of each sentence on the `df1` which has a topic associated to it. The embedding is in 'column 1' in `df2` which has a string of list of positive or negative integers of size 512.

My desired output DataFrame is:

**df_output.shape = (4,514)**

| Text | Topic | Feature_0 | Feature_2 | …. | Feature_511 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Where is the party tonight? | Party | -0.0115705 | -0.01011708 | …. | 0.0624484 |
| Let's dance | Party | -0.082681999 | -0.00161403 | …. | 0.020942 |
| Hello world | Other | -0.063768424 | -0.01590338535606861, | …. | 0.020942 |
| It is rainy today | Weather | 0.06379614 | -0.028780641 | …. | 0.056790903 |

How can I get this done. I was trying to split the embeddings in the DataFrame `df2` into columns but it doesn't work for me. This is what I have done so far:

```
df2.join(pd.DataFrame(df2["1"].values.tolist()).add_prefix('feature_'))
```

It just created a duplicate column 1 as `feature_0`. I haven't even reached to the stage where I can work to join `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: Maybe it's not lists but rather strings in column "1". Try `import ast; df2.join(pd.DataFrame(df2["1"].apply(ast.literal_eval).values.tolist()).add_prefix('feature_'))`

Comment: Hi, Enke. It is a list for sure. I have verified it for full length:
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
df2['1'][0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map `ast.literal_eval` to items in `df2["1"]`; build a DataFrame and `join` it to `df1`:

```
import ast
out = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(map(ast.literal_eval, df2["1"].tolist())).add_prefix('feature_'))
```

Output:

```
                          Text    Topic  feature_0  feature_1  feature_2
0  Where is the party tonight?    Party  -0.011571  -0.010117   0.062448
1                  Let's dance    Party  -0.082682  -0.001614   0.020942
2                  Hello world    Other  -0.063768  -0.015903   0.020942
3            It is rainy today  Weather   0.063796  -0.028781   0.056791
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {0: ['Where is the party tonight?', "Let's dance", 'Hello world', 'It is rainy today'],
1:[[-0.011570500209927559, -0.010117080062627792,0.062448356],[-0.08268199861049652, -0.0016140303341671824,0.02094201],[-0.0637684240937233, -0.01590338535606861,0.02094201],[0.06379614025354385, -0.02878064103424549,0.056790903]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# mind NO values here
exploded_df = pd.DataFrame(df[1].to_list(), index=df.index)

print(exploded_df.head())
```

**Output:**

```
          0         1         2
0 -0.011571 -0.010117  0.062448
1 -0.082682 -0.001614  0.020942
2 -0.063768 -0.015903  0.020942
3  0.063796 -0.028781  0.056791
```

You could then join both dfs.